# How to get role name depending on the name of users?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a table named `role_users` which I have 3 columns: `id`, `user_id` and `role_id` and table `Users` with all users.I need to get id role for every user in my site because I want to use an icon for `individuals` ( id 1) and another icon for `organizations`(id 100).
My Roles table is here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQbIZ.jpg .

**Controller.php**

```
$myRole = Role::join(
                    'users', 
                    function($join) {
                        $join->on('roles.id', '=', 'users.id');
                    }
                )
                ->groupBy('users.id')
                ->selectRaw(
                    implode(',', [
                        'users.id AS id', 
                    ])
                )
                ->get();
 return view('noticeboard.noticeboard',$data)
             ->with(compact('myRole'));
```

**dd($myRole)**

```
[{"id":1}];
```

**View**

```
@if($myRole->id == 1)
<a   href="{{ url('') }}/{{ $contact->username }}">{{ $contact->username  }}</a></h3>
<i class="icon-user"></i>
@else
<i class="icon-trophy"></i>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try eloquent relations for this one.

In your User Model define hasOne relation with role

```
   public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Role','user_id');
    }
```

then in Controller use Eager Loading

```
$users = User::with('role')->get();
return view('noticeboard.noticeboard',compact('users'));
```

and then in view use foreach loop to get all users with roles

```
    @foreach($users as $user)
    @if($user->role->id == 1)
    <a   href="{{ url('').'/'.$user->username }}">{{ $user->username  }}</a></h3>
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    @else
    <i class="icon-trophy"></i>
    @endif
    @endforeach
```

Unless you realy don't want to use relationships. Then use join on 'users' table.